# Why does KangarooTwelve only use 12 rounds?

Tags: hash, keccak

The initial Keccak submission used 18 rounds, which was [bumped up to 24 rounds](http://keccak.noekeon.org/version_2.0.html) for the final version after [distinguishers were found](http://keccak.noekeon.org/NoteZeroSum.pdf) for a reduced 16 round variant.  However, the Keccak team has recently released a spate of cryptographic primitives based on a twelve-round variant of Keccak.

I've seen [scattered references](http://christina-boura.info/sites/default/files/presentation_5.pdf) which give the impression that [new bounds were found](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Anne.Canteaut/Publications/Canteaut_Boura13.pdf) and that even 18 rounds is overkill.  However, I can't grok the research and I need a canonical answer.

What led them to feel comfortable with 12 rounds for K12?

Comment: I think the big reason is that it only claims 128-bit security, one of my possible recommendations for SHA-3 was to reduce the round count where a lower security was claimed, and that is exactly what they have done here

Comment: Hash functions allow an attacker more control than keyed primitives

Comment: @Indolering, I updated my answer.

Comment: @RichieFrame but SHA-3 only claims to provide 128-256 bits of security.

Comment: that is collision security, there is also preimage security, distinguisher security, etc

Comment: @Indolering I don't understand your question. references (cf ref 25) in the paper you linked point to bounds found in 2011, thus the note by the keccak authors still hold.

Comment: The slides indicate incremental improvements in 2011 and 2013, the note was published in 2010.  I don't understand the math, I've emailed the author and the Keccak team but never got a response : (

Answer (score 8):

### I. Intuition: collision only on 6 rounds.

KangarooTwelve aims at fast hashing but also claims 128-bits security. This can be seen in the fact that the capacity is set to 256 allowing a rate of 1344 for a faster absorption.

Note that while the base sponge construction uses only the 12 finals rounds of Keccak, it is applied twice *on each bit* in the case of a message longer than 8129 bytes. You compute first the *CV*s values and then hash it with the first string (see bellow).

```
KangarooTwelve(M,C):  S_0 || S_1 || ... || S_n = M || C
  F = Sponge[Keccak-p[1600,nr=12],r=1344,c=256] (or mini Keccak)

                          +------------+
                          |    S_0     |
                          +------------+
                               ||
                          +----------+
                          |  `110*`  |
                          +----------+
                               ||
+-----------------+   F   +----------+
|     S_1  ||`110`|------>|   CV_0   |
+-----------------+       +----------+
                               ||
+-----------------+   F   +----------+
|     S_2  ||`110`|------>|   CV_1   |
+-----------------+       +----------+
                               ||
       ...                    ...
                               ||
+-----------------+   F   +----------+
|     S_n  ||`110`|------>|  CV_n-1  |
+-----------------+       +----------+
                               ||
                          +----------+
                          | r_e(n-1) |
                          +----------+
                               ||
                          +------------------+   F
                          |  0xFFFF  || `01` |------>  output
                          +------------------+
```

Other reasons that lead to consider K12 safe are the current absence of collisions for more than 6 rounds, implying a security margin of 100%. This same round-reduced approach is also used in Keyak and Ketje.

If you want to have more security, you can use *Marsupilami 14*, it is Kangaroo 12 but with the last 14 rounds of Keccak instead of 12 and a capacity of 512 bits.

### II. The complexity arguments.

Joan pointed this to me: in this [note](http://keccak.noekeon.org/NoteZeroSum.pdf), it is noted that the complexity of the zero-sum distinguisher are

- for 18 rounds: $2^{1370}$
- for 14 rounds: $2^{257}$
- for 12 rounds: $2^{129}$

In the case of **KangarooTwelve**, the **capacity is 256 bits**. A generic attack on a sponge with such capacity leads to a complexity of $2^{128}$, thus the complexity of the **zero-sum distinguisher** for 12 rounds is higher, rendering the **efficiency** of this attack **worse than bruteforce**.

As for the 14 rounds of MarsupilamiFourteen and its capacity of 512 bits, the arguments is the same.

Also to generate the zero-sum structure, one need to start in the middle of the iterations. This attack surface is reduced by the way KangarooTweleve operates due to all the fixed constants.

Comment: That note was written in response to those attacks but recent research seems to have improved those bounds: [paper](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Anne.Canteaut/Publications/Canteaut_Boura13.pdf), [slides](http://christina-boura.info/sites/default/files/presentation_5.pdf).